# auth0 auth0-spa-js must run on a secure origin angular

Tags: angular, auth0

I hope someone can help me out here, I have found no help anywhere else.
I have created a site using auth0 and angular universal.

I followed their documentation and it all seemed to be working ok; but now I have deployed it to azure, the site never loads. I have done some digging and found that it's saying this:

> auth0-spa-js must run on a secure origin. See https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-do-i-get-auth0-spa-js-must-run-on-a-secure-origin for more information.

I have no idea why this is happening as I am running it on a secure host (https://86sparks-develop-website.azurewebsites.net/) and I have tried running it on a server with a valid SSL certificate, as well as locally using a self generated certificate, but they all throw this error.

I believe it has something to do with using Angular Universal, but I can't see what is causing the issue.
Has anyone else had issue with auth0 and angular universal?